# How To Set Logon Expiry in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, expired-sessions

Reference:
[Building Your First Web API with ASP.NET Core MVC and Visual Studio](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html)

Scenario:
(a) a .NET Core 1.0 Web API solution was built using the above link.
(b) That solution was run in Debug mode.
(c) a user registered
(d) that user logged on
(e) many hours later that user is still logged on

Still in the same Debug session, this code gets executed:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
```

My unfulfilled *expectation* was that the above mentioned user's logon would have timed out; however, `Hello *example user*!` and `Log off` are again rendered to the **navbar**; clicking `Log off` does log off the *example user*.

So how does one set an expiry time in ASP.NET Core Identity so that
(a) a logged on user can be logged off after a fixed time period like 8 hours,
(b) a logged on user can be logged off after a fixed period of inactivity like 30 minutes?

Answer (score 7):

To answer your questions:

Q: a logged on user can be logged off after a fixed time period like 8 hours
A: Set the `ExpireTimeSpan` on the cookie options to 8 hours.

Q: a logged on user can be logged off after a fixed period of inactivity like 30 minutes?
A: Set the `ExpireTimeSpan` to 30 minutes and set `SlidingExpiration` to `True`.

Read https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html#adding-and-configuring and 
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html#controlling-cookie-options for details.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion; is there a cookie-*less* solution?

Comment: Using JWT can be cookieless, depending on your implementation. 

Based on your comment I suggest Googling "web authentication mechanisms" and "the stateless nature of HTTP" to get you started on your web delopment journey.